# How to add a gradient layer to an expandable cell in UIViewTable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, cagradientlayer

I have a UITableView that has cells of the same height. When the user taps one of the cells then the cell will expand in the bottom of it, it will show a new section in addition that is not the original cell that was shown before the tap. If the cells are A, B, C, D

then tapping B will make the UITableView look like

A, B + b, C, D

(for instance, if a user taps on C, the new view 'c' can be in different height of that of 'b')

where b is a UIView that is relevant to the cell B.

The data in 'b' will expand with animation to its height.

I built all of my app with autolayout and I have autoresizing cells with autolayout. How can I add a gradient to the back of 'b' that will expand in tandem with the content of 'b' and the animation on it?

Thanks

added a class I wrote to contain the gradient in a UIView as Evgeny Karkan suggested:

```
import UIKit

class UIGradient: UIView {

    var colors: [UIColor]!

    init(colors: [UIColor]) {

        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        self.colors = colors

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        super.layoutSubviews()



        DelayUtil.delay(0.1) {

            self.addGradient(self.colors)

        }



    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {

        if self.superview != nil {

            self.stretchToBoundsOfSuperView()

            self.superview?.sendSubviewToBack(self)

        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}


extension UIView {


    func addGradient(colors: [UIColor]) -> CAGradientLayer {

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)

        if colors.count >= 2 {

            gradient.colors = [colors[0].CGColor, colors[1].CGColor]

        }

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
        return gradient

    }

}
```

Comment: Add gradient view to your cell, hide it, on expanding event - show it.

Comment: but the gradient doesn't resize itself to the frame of the UIView on which I applied it, isn't it? when I try to do that I end up with the full size of gradient showing in the beginning of the cell expansion animation

Comment: Yeah, correct, you need to resize it smoothly, as I understand you. Try to pin with constraints gradient view's bottom to bottom of your cell.

Comment: I think I understood what you meant, I tried it and still it didn't work. I attached the class I wrote for that propose, I will also try to upload a GIF that shows the results

Comment: this is the current result http://imgur.com/a/9hQrn in the middle I turned on the slow animations feature so it will be more clear what's going on

Comment: Is `clipsToBounds=true` for the view you are adding the `UIGradient` to?

Comment: it did it, it works. for some reason i didn't even think about it, i thought about animating the gradient height, i guess it happens when you're working 12 hours straight. thanks a lot :)